# Stable or unstable differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

In a lecture, I saw that following differential equation is unstable but I don't really see why it is unstable. I explain my arguments in the following

I have

$$\frac{dm\left(t\right)}{dt}=m\left(t\right)+b$$

where $b$ is a constant parameter, it can be negative or positive.

In order to find a general solution, I convert the problem by multiplying each sides by $e^{-at}$ to

$$\left(\frac{dm\left(t\right)}{dt}-m\left(t\right)\right)e^{-at}=b.e^{-at}$$

I integrate between $0$ and $\infty$ ;

$$\int_{0}^{\infty}\left(\frac{dm\left(t\right)}{dt}-m\left(t\right)\right)e^{-at}ds=\int_{0}^{\infty}b.e^{-at}ds$$

where $\left(\frac{dm\left(t\right)}{dt}-m\left(t\right)\right)e^{-at}=\left[\frac{d}{dt}\left(m\left(t\right)e^{-at}\right)\right]$

I write the problem

$$\left[m\left(t\right)e^{-at}\right]_{0}^{\infty}=\left[-\frac{be^{-at}}{a}\right]_{0}^{\infty}$$

which yields

$$m\left(t\right)=\frac{b}{a}$$

As the general solution does not explode (we don't have anymore an expression with exponential), I can not see why this differential equation is unstable.
Any hints or suggestions ?

Comment: first of all, i think u can set $a = 1$ as there is no point to introduce such a variable. secondly, u may want to follow the method of solving a linear DE where indefinite integral is used, but not from $0$ to $\infty$. Then $e^{-t}$ will be the key point to show the instability.

Comment: 1. The solution $b/a$ does not satisfy the DE (even with the correct $a=1$). 2. It is *one* "solution" (the stationary solution), but stability is the property of *all* solutions. 3. You can win some time by changing $y(t)=m(t)+b$ which does not affect stability (why?)

Comment: Either a phase diagram (instanteneous solution) or the explicit solution $$m(t)=(m(0)+b)e^t-b$$ shows that $m(t)\to\pm\infty$ when $t\to\infty$, depending on the sign of $m(0)+b$, for every $m(0)$ except $m(0)=-b$, in which case $m(t)=-b$ for every $t$. "Unstable" refers to the fact that for every starting point not equal to $-b$, even close to the fixed point $-b$, $|m(t)|\to\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

$$\frac{dm\left(t\right)}{dt}=m\left(t\right)+b$$

or

$$\dot m=m+b$$

for short, laplace transformed

$$sM=M+b$$

$$M=\frac{b}{s-1}$$

has a pole at 1 which shows the instability because $\Re(1) = 1 \gt0$